# Add dynamic based image to the top corner of ActiveAdmin menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've seen the manual like this one:

```
   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
     admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
       menu.add label: "ActiveAdmin.info", url: "http://www.activeadmin.info",
                                      html_options: { target: :blank }
     end
     admin.add_current_user_to_menu  menu
     admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
   end
```

But if I want to add something like admin's image I can't handle this with standard methods, I've solved this like this:

```
   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
      menu.add label: 'current_user_logo', url: proc { current_user.image }
   end
```

And js code like this:

```
   $ ->
     element = $("#current_user_logo")
     obj = element.find("a")
     href = obj.attr('href')
     append_place = $("#current_user")
     append_place.after("<img src="+href+" height='40'>")
     element.remove()
```

But it looks like a hack, any better solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will work for you

> config.site_title_image = ->(view) { current_user.image}

Comment: It appears on the top left corner, but I need top right instead

Comment: Got to app/assets/ 
stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss and add styles in there. To see the 
styles that are used by active admin to overwrite them easier go here: 
https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin 
Also to change the image style really easily just go to the link below and 
change overwrite these variables. Make sure to overwrite them above 
the @import "active_admin/base";
https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_variables.css.scss